# Security.Principal and Security.Permissions Samples

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, c#-4.0

Where I can Find some Example about `Security.Principal` and `Security.Permissions`?

I want to develop a Winform login form and Webform login page and manage their security.I want to know how and how much this 2 namespaces help me.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give you are using windows forms, your best bet will be to use the WindowsPrincipal class.  Do you have access to an active directory?  What are you trying to secure?

If your app just uses a flat file for the database, all you really need is to set an ACL on the file it uses, windows will stop any app, not just yours from accessing the file.  Or do you need to access resources remotely, like WCF, SQL, Web services.

We need a little info and we can give you a better answer.  But in lieu of that, you are definately better off not writing any code other than a check of the user's group or WindowsPrincipal.IsAdministrator for instance as a check in your app.  If that's the route you are going to take, then you need to consider UAC in Windows Vista/7.

More info please:

Comment: I want to develop a login for winapp using AD.problem is grouping my user is different than AD groups.and for login in webapp what security consideration I must consider? thanks

Comment: The WindowsPrincipal will represent the user as your applications context is running as.  Usually this is the logged on user except when the app is started using `runas /user:SpecialUserxyz`.  You can then use the windows principal to get the name of the user and then hit the domain using the System.DirectoryServices classes.